# Equivalent class for marshal/unmarshal of this xml file

Tags: java, xml, marshalling, unmarshalling

What is the equivalent class to marshal/unmarshal this xml file in java?

```
<display-type>
        <value default="true">Document</value>
        <value>GenericNode:144</value>
  </display-type>
```

Comment: What have you tried ? We are here to help, not to give you the answer ootb.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@XmlRootElement(name = DisplayType.DISPLAY_TYPE)
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.NONE)
public class DisplayType {

    static final String DISPLAY_TYPE = "display-type";
    private static final String DEFAULT = "default";


    @XmlAttribute(name = DEFAULT)
    private Boolean defaultName;


    @XmlValue
    private String name;
}
```